# Adding class to multiple elements with the same class

Tags: javascript

I'm used to use jQuery in my projects but I want to do this using only plain JS, I tried this:

```
//Open overlay
document.querySelector('.gallery__img').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('showOverlay');
});

// Close overlay
document.querySelector('#closeOverlay').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.remove('showOverlay');
});
```

But it didn't work, how naive of me thinking it'll be as easy as using jQuery... With the code above only when I click the first element the class is added, but it doesn't work with the rest.

the HTMl looks like this:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="img/hg-1.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-2.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-3.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-4.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-5.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-6.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-7.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-8.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-9.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-10.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-11.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-12.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
</div>
```

Comment: I thought this seems so simple that an example is not needed, I just want to add a class to the elements with the class "gallery__img" whenever I click one of those elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.querySelector('.gallery__img')` will return the first `img` tag that it finds in the HTML.

If you want to bind the event listener to all the `img`s, you need to use `document.querySelectorAll` and need to loop over the collection to bind the listener.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__img').forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('click', function() { ... });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener to *all* elements (with `.querySelectorAll` and `forEach` or some other loop). Adding an event listener to the element returned by `querySelector` only adds a listener to that one element (the first one that matches), not to all elements matching the selector.

Or, you might use event delegation instead - add only a single listener, to `.gallery`, check to see if the target matches `.gallery__img`, and if it does, toggle the `classList` of every child:

```js
const gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery');
gallery.onclick = (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches('.gallery__img')) return;
  [...gallery.children].forEach(child => child.classList.add('showOverlay'));
}
```

```css
.showOverlay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="img/hg-1.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-2.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-3.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-4.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-5.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-6.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-7.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-8.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-9.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-10.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-11.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-12.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
</div>
```